# Error in NetBeans (connected via SQlite) Using Radio Buttons

Tags: sqlite, netbeans

The program given below is not executing the rs1(Result set query) rather it is directly moving into the catch block). I'm not able to identify the error. Help please.

```
private void EnterActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{                                      
   Calendar cal=new GregorianCalendar();
   int minute =cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
   int hours=cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    String time1=minute+":"+hours;
    String s=Login_page.id+"";
    String sql="UPDATE emp_info SET intime=? where empid=?";

    try
    {
        switch (time) 
        {
            case "intime":
                {

                    //"Update emp_info set intime='"+time1+"' where empid=?";
                    System.out.println(time+Login_page.id); 
                    PreparedStatement pst1=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                    pst.setString(1,time1);
                    pst.setString(2,s);
                    System.out.println(time+Login_page.id); 
                    ResultSet rs1=pst.executeQuery();
                    if(rs.next())
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"In time registered");

                    }

                    break;
                }
            case "outtime":
                {
                    //String sql="Insert into emp_info (outtime) values (?) where empid='"+Login_page.id+"'";

                   //pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                    //pst.setString(1,time1);
                    //pst.setString(2,Login_page.user);
                    //rs=pst.executeQuery();
                    PreparedStatement pst2=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                    pst.setString(1,time1);
                    pst.setString(2,s);
                    System.out.println(time+Login_page.id); 
                    ResultSet rs2=pst.executeQuery();
                    if(rs.next())
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"In time registered");

                    }
                    break;
                }
        }
}                                     
        catch(Exception e)
    { 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"ERROR","ERROR",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    }


}
```

Comment: the two System.out.println is used to check the execution flow.

Comment: When you want to add something to your question you can edit your question instead of posting a comment. Could you in your catch clause output the message of the exception: e.getMessage() and post what it says in your question? It may shed a light on what is happening.

Comment: It's not necessary to SHOUT your questions. Typing in ALL CAPS makes your question harder to read, is annoying, and doesn't help you get an answer faster. Also, please take the time to properly format your code. You can see it in a WYSIWYG preview immediately below the text area where you're entering it, so you can see in real-time what your post will look like. Formatting it makes it easier to read, and improves the chances you'll get an answer. Thanks.